# Received byte array containing bitmap returns null

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to send an image from one device to another using the BluetoothChat sample from Google. I can send string value from device to device but I'm having problems sending images. I have two classes handling the receiving and sending of data.

For sending images, I convert the image path to bitmap then convert it to byte[] and pass that to the utility class, same as the BluetoothChat sample but with increased buffer size (1024 default, changed it to 8192). My code for the BluetoothSend class that sends data to the utility class is this,

```
send.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

            int width = bitmap.getRowBytes();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            int bmpSize = width * height;

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bmpSize);
            bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);

            byte[] byteArray = byteBuffer.array();
            sendUtils.write(byteArray);

            bitmap.recycle();
    });
```

This is the utility class that handles the sending and receiving of data,

```
/**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothsocket;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        bluetoothsocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = bluetoothsocket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = bluetoothsocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ConnectedThrd->Cons", "Socket not created.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        inputStream = tmpIn;
        outputStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; //1024 original
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    handler.obtainMessage(BluetoothSend.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    handler.obtainMessage(BluetoothReceive.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (NullPointerException n) {
                    Log.e("ConnectedThrd->Run", n.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("ConnectedThrd->Run", "Connection Lost.", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            try {
                outputStream.write(buffer);
                handler.obtainMessage(BluetoothSend.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
                handler.obtainMessage(BluetoothReceive.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (NullPointerException n) {
                Log.e("ConnectedThrd->Write", "Bluetooth Socket is null: " + n.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ConnectedThread->Write", "Empty write stream.");
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothsocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ConnectedThread->Cancel", "Failed to close socket.");
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, on the BluetoothReceive class, I receive the data using a handler. Code for handler object is as follows,

```
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                //Read message from sender
                byte[] bufferRead = (byte[]) message.obj;
                //bitmap decodedByte is null
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bufferRead, 0, bufferRead.length);
                int height = decodedByte.getHeight();
                int width = decodedByte.getWidth();

                Bitmap.Config config = Bitmap.Config.valueOf(decodedByte.getConfig().name());
                Bitmap bitmap_tmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bufferRead);
                bitmap_tmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
                fileView.setImageBitmap(bitmap_tmp);
                break;
```

I seem to always get a null value when I try to convert the byte array received from the other device when I convert it to a bitmap so I can use it to display it in an ImageView.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `convert the image path to bitmap then convert it to byte[] and pass` Not a good idea as the amount of bitmap bytes will be much larger then the file size of the .jpg file you started with. Just send the file.

Comment: @blackapps I've used `File.readAllBytes(filePath)` when I send a txt file to the other device. It works. But, would it work on media files too?

Comment: You should first tell where this function stores the readed bytes. If it is in a byte array then send that array as you do now.

Comment: @blackapps, I've tried doing that. I can send the byte array to the other device but I can't use that data to be used as an image source.

Comment: Why not????????

Comment: When I convert it to a bitmap, it returns null when getting the length of the byte array.

Comment: If the length of the byte array is null then why do you even try to convert it to bitmap?

Comment: I can receive the byte array on the receiver side because I can see the converted string value of the bitmap. I don't know why it returns null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you can pass strings. You can convert bitmap to `Base64` string format and sent it.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("filePath");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); 
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

On receiving side, reverse it (String `Base64` to image)

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: Base 64 is 30% more bytes to transfer.

Comment: Further you use an intermediate bitmap which is  not needed as one can base64 encode the original file. Less code, quicker and keeping original file.

Comment: Sometimes we need to scale down image before transfering. So, bitmap is useful to reduce resolution and can be compressed as well,.

Comment: I'll try this one later. I hope it works.

Comment: @Sohaib Ahmed, should my path look like, '/storage/emulated/0/myDir/myFile"?

Comment: Yes, your filePath can be like this

Comment: I'm having a hard time decoding the byte array received on the other side. I can only pass bytes not strings. I tried receiving the bytes first, convert it to String for the encodedImage, convert it to byte array again then to bitmap. Am I doing it right? Because I get a bad base.64 value.

Comment: It's a lengthy approach, I think you first need to achieve what required, after that you can find some best practices.

Comment: @SohaibAhmed, I just need to send an image using Bluetooth socket. Using INTENT ACTION_SEND is not an option because I am to send it programatically.

Comment: I got it, did you successfully received on the other hand.

Comment: @SohaibAhmed, Yes. My only problem is, I am having problems converting the received byte array on the receiving side to a Bitmap. I only get the message, "failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented' ".

Comment: can you show me the code of converting byte-array to bitmap?

Comment: `case MESSAGE_READ:
                    //Read message from sender
                    byte[] bufferRead = (byte[]) message.obj;
                    if (bufferRead.length > 0) {
                        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bufferRead, 0, bufferRead.length);
                        fileView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    } else {
                        displayToast("Empty byte array received.");
                    }
                    break;`